# Multi line text field in REST API filter url

Tags: filter, sharepoint-rest-api, multiline-text-field

I want to filter the field with data type Multi line text, but somehow am not able to filter that. I guess this didn't work as it contains html code within it, between the div tag my text appears.

Below is the filter URL

```
url :_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site')/items?$select=Title,Keywords&$filter=Keywords contains 'test'"
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try it as below:

```
_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Site')/items?$select=Title,Keywords&$filter=substringof('test',Keywords)
```

If that doesnt work, you need to create a POST request as below:

```
function postJson(endpointUrl,payload,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      url: endpointUrl, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}

function getListItems(listTitle, queryViewXml,success,failure)
{
   var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        } 
   }; 
   var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
   postJson(endpointUrl,queryPayload,
     function(data){
        success(data.d.results);    
     },failure);
}
```

How to use it:

```
getListItems('Site',"<View><Query><Where><Contains><FieldRef Name='Keywords'/><Value Type='Note'>test</Value></Contains></Where></Query></View>",
  function(items){       
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items);   
      }
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  });
```

Reference - [Using CAML with REST API](https://chuvash.eu/2014/03/25/using-caml-with-sharepoint-rest-api/)

Comment: Time we learn people Functional Programming, Gautam. Your for loop has a typo, always displays all items. In FP that typo is difficult to make; its ``items.forEach(function(item){console.log(item)})`` Since it takes a Function (*that's why its called [Functional Programming.. its not magic](https://medium.com/@yannickdot/functional-programming-101-6bc132674ec5#.ko2m7ut1t)*); you could do ``items.forEach(console.log)`` that will log all 3 parameters: value, index (the i in your for loop) and the whole array items