# Multi level filter sharepoint rest api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-rest-api, error

I have a multi Folder/UniqueId column. I need to apply rest API filter on this column.

```
_api/Web/Lists/getbytitle('testList')/items?$filter=(Folder/UniqueId eq 'abctest')
```

Getting below exception.

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "-2146232832, Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-US",
            "value": "Column 'Folder' does not exist. It may have been deleted by another user."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What is the name and data type of your column? And in REST APIs you need to use the [internal name](https://plumsail.com/docs/help-desk-o365/v1.x/How%20To/Find%20the%20internal%20name%20of%20SharePoint%20column.html) of your columns.

Answer (score 0):

If your column name is Folder/UniqueId,the column internal name is Folder_x002f_UniqueId.

If the column is a multi text column,the value may not be the ‘testabc’,you could use “`/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('listname')/items`” to get all column value.

And the a multi text column can not use filter in rest, you need to call caml to filter .

Demo:

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

function postJson(endpointUrl,payload,success,failure)
{
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST", 
      headers: { 
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "content-type": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
      }, 
      data: JSON.stringify(payload),
      url: endpointUrl, 
      success: success,
      failure: failure 
   });
}

function getListItems(listTitle, queryViewXml,success,failure)
{
   var queryPayload = { 
       'query':{ 
           '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' },
           'ViewXml': queryViewXml
        } 
   }; 
   var endpointUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems";
   postJson(endpointUrl,queryPayload,
     function(data){
        success(data.d.results);    
     },failure);
}
getListItems('Contents',"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Folder_x002f_UniqueId' /><Value Type='Note'>1</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>",
  function(items){       
      for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
          console.log(items[i]);   
      }
  },
  function(error){
     console.log(JSON.stringify(error)); 
  });
</script>
```

[Multi line text field in REST API filter url](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/209051/multi-line-text-field-in-rest-api-filter-url)